# Number of swaps in merge-sort (Python)

Tags: python, count, swap, mergesort

How should I find number of swaps done in a merge sort , here is the algorithm. The count computation was done , the problem is : the count variable is not returned.

```
count=0
def mergesort(elist,count):
    #print(count)
    low=0
    high=len(elist)
    #print(len(elist))
    if len(elist)<2:
       return elist
    mid=int((low+high)/2)
    enlist=[]
    y=mergesort(elist[:mid],count)
    z=mergesort(elist[mid:high],count)
    i=0
    j=0

while(i<len(y) and j<len(z)):
    if y[i]<=z[j]:
       enlist.append(y[i])
       i+=1

    else:
         count+=abs((len(y)+1)-i)
         enlist.append(z[j])
         j+=1

enlist+=y[i:];
enlist+=z[j:]

return enlist,count








i=0
list=[2,1,3,4,5,6,7]

print(mergesort(list,0))
```

if there is an error with swap count do correct that too.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean "unable to return"? Please indent your code correctly and explain the problem more precisely.

Comment: Please reformat your code so it does run. Copy-pasting it returns a SyntaxError on 29 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you new to `Python`? You've just missed indentation.
Please correct it. 
[More About Indentaiont](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html).

Your code should be like this.

```
def mergesort(elist, count):  
    #st1 
    #st2
    while..
        #st3
        #st4
    return count
```

Note the indentations.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to `return` outside of a function, try replacing the `return` with `print`

```
...
print enlist,count
```